# How are related basic/constructionist theories of emotions and James-Lange-Theory/Cannon-Bard-Theory/... of emotions?

Tags: emotion

In this [SE question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/what-causes-emotions) about "What causes emotions?", there are two answers, one which discusses the distinction between basic emotion theorists (Ekman) and constructionists (Russell, Watson), and the other which discusses a set of theories of emotions which seem to have no relation with the theories of the first answer (James-Lange-Theory, Cannon-Bard-Theory, Schachter-Singer-Theory).

How are related basic/constructionist theories of emotions and James-Lange-Theory/Cannon-Bard-Theory/... of emotions?

And also the conceptors of the James-Lange-Theory, Cannon-Bard-Theory, Schachter-Singer-Theory seem to be born a long time ago, so I wonder if the theories are outdated.

Comment: [This great paper](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1754073909338877) on the history of emotion theories may be helpful - particularly [Figure 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2835158/figure/F1/): Early theorists contributed ideas to multiple modern theories that are presumably more refined.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Thank you very much for the paper, very helpful. And also for redirecting to Figure 1!